# Set value to an ion-select-box with dynamic ion-select-option

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to learn ionic.
The Code along with screen shots is in Google Drive link (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fw6zIjyczHReM2Ddb_jtCO4GAlgFjM7v?usp=sharing)

I am clicking on (+) in screen 1 to to open a model in like screen 2.
I have filled the details and Click on add.

On clicking Add button I am adding the district and closing the modal and trying to set the selected district in screen three to screen 4 below using code.
this.form.patchValue({'stateCode': stateCode});

But It's not working.

I want the output like screen 5 when click on Add button in Screen 3.

I observed that In district.page.html,
If I use the ion-select-option like

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.stateCode" >{{state.stateName}}</ion-select-option>
```

I am getting the output like  Screen 4

If I use the ion-select-option like

```
<ion-select-option  value=""> Select District</ion-select-option> 
 <ion-select-option  value="1"> Andhra Pradesh</ion-select-option>
 <ion-select-option  value="2">Arunachal Pradesh</ion-select-option>
```

I am getting the output like screen 5.

But I wanted to get the screen 5 output with `<ion-select-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.stateCode" >{{state.stateName}}</ion-select-option>`

Please help me to solve the problem and learn
If any data required. Please tell me I will share.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your Code to your Question. stop using Images for code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have set ngModel attribute in the ion-select but you don't mention it.

You should somehow define the state id from screen 3 in a variable like `state.form.id`

Check if your id from screen 3 matches the id in the `ngFor` loop and set it with the `[selected]` attribute

```
<ion-select [ngModel]="state.form.id">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let state of states" [selected]="state.form.id = state.id" [value]="state.stateCode" >{{state.stateName}}</ion-select-option> 
</ion-select>
```